# How to get nonce from Braintree iOs SDK

Tags: ios, paypal, braintree, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to get nonce from Braintree. I have not found any documentation Braintree provided that how to get nonce from Braintree SDK in following documentation.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4

Please let me know how to get nonce from Braintree iOs SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Getting the nonce is documented in the [Presenting Drop-in UI section](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4#present-drop-in-ui) of the page you linked. Once you have the Drop-in active, you need to implement a delegate so the Drop-in can find where to send the nonce it produces. Without a delegate like the one specified you won't receive the nonce from the Drop-in: 
​

> Then implement BTDropInViewControllerDelegate to obtain the payment method nonce on success, and dismiss the Drop In UI in either case:

```
- (void)dropInViewController:(BTDropInViewController *)viewController   
  didSucceedWithTokenization:(BTPaymentMethodNonce *)paymentMethodNonce {
    // Send payment method nonce to your server for processing
    [self postNonceToServer:paymentMethodNonce.nonce];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

 - (void)dropInViewControllerDidCancel:(__unused BTDropInViewController *)viewController {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

​
If you look at the first function you can see that a variable `paymentMethodNonce` (type: BTPaymentMethodNonce) is passed into your app. This sample code expects that you have another function (`postNonceToServer`) to actually handle the nonce once you get it.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso The new Braintree iOS Drop-in takes a completion callback that returns a `BTDropInResult` object, which contains the payment method nonce. (Disclosure: I work at Braintree)

Comment: how to convert payment method nonce to nssting? @Richard Shin

Comment: @Jason The `nonce` property of `BTPaymentMethodNonce` is an `NSString`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get Payment nonce in drop in method by using
 let nonce = result.paymentMethod!.nonce

Example :-

```
func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
    let request =  BTDropInRequest()
    let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
    { (controller, result, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR")
        } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
            print("CANCELLED")
        } else if let result = result {

            let nonce = result.paymentMethod!.nonce

            print( nonce)

        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```